# Is high inflation an indication of a recession, either now or in the near future?

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, recession

I have been wondering about this. Perhaps one example of a recession without inflation would settle this quicky?

Comment: also https://www.frbsf.org/economic-research/publications/economic-letter/2009/march/risk-deflation/#2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not. For example, following Romer Advanced Macroeconomics 4th ed pp 193 from 11 recessions that occurred between 1947 and 2009 inflation increased in only 6 of those recessions.

Also, average change in inflation during all 11 recessions was -0.03% which means that on average recessions are slightly deflationary although the number is very close to zero.

Hence some recessions are accompanied by inflation and some aren't. The split is almost 50/50. Consequently, just observing inflation without looking at any other variables does not provide good indication of whether we are in recession or not.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What confused me is the title of article in The Economist: "American inflation tops forecasts yet again, adding to recession risks" (Source: https://www.economist.com/finance-and-economics/2022/07/13/american-inflation-tops-forecasts-yet-again-adding-to-recession-risks). It seems to consider 'inflation' as a variable important for monitoring a possible economic recession.

Comment: @StatsScared yea but if you read pass the headline they explain that the inflation is driven by, among other things, energy getting more scarce. High energy prices can lead both to recession and inflation at the same time

Comment: thanks, yes for sure. But still odd to try to make a inflation<>recession connection. But I guess the purpose of headlines is not exactly to be accurate..